# Accessing embedded Solr instance over HTTP

Tags: web-applications, solr

I'm running an embedded Solr instance inside a webapp. What is the best way to provide direct (or proxied via the webapp) HTTP access to the Solr instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct access through http for the embedded solr is not an option.
you would need to route the queries to Embedded Solr through your web application, which would query on the solr instance an return back the results.

Using Embedded Solr forever is not much recommended. If you hosting a webapp why not very well host solr as well ?

Comment: Not sure if its  recommended as well. Quote from site - The simplest, safest, way to use Solr is via Solr's standard HTTP interfaces. Embedding Solr is less flexible, harder to support, not as well tested, and should be reserved for special circumstances.